# how to use windows 7 host usb devices in Ubuntu14.04 guest in vbox5.0.10?

Tags: 14.04, usb, virtualbox

I am using Windows 7 as host OS and VirtualBox 5.0.10 and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I already installed the guest extension pack and still I am not seeing any connected USB devices in Ubuntu guest. I tried to add VBoxUsers group also but terminal said VBoxUsers as no group found. I used following code:

```
~$ sudo usermod -a -G VBoxUsers <usrName>
```

Please help me friends.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't turn up in the selection list of the USB entry under the VirtualBox frame's Devices menu?

Comment: yes exactly this is the issue and I also tried to add in VBoxUsers but not worked...

Comment: Well, if it's missing from that list, then I would think the issue concerns running virtualbox on windows 7, and not related to the guest OS at all. I suppose you've made sure you've ticked the USB box in the virtualbox settings for the machine... you'll probably need to contact virtualbox support/forum.